# How does this function self-executes?

Tags: javascript, function, execution

I have the following code (which is the initialization of the facebook API),
I don't understand why this snippet runs on-load without being called anywhere else in the code!

The funny thing is that when i remove the `fbAsyncInit function` "wrapper" it works the same!
so how does the `FB.init` is called without calling `fbAsyncInit` anywhere else?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '00000000000000000', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            console.log('User is logged in.');
            FB.api("/me?fields=name,picture", handleMe);
        }
        else {
            console.log('User is not logged in.');
            window.location = "http://wall-et.com/index.php/test/login/";
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work, you need to include a script from Facebook (perhaps [connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js)) in your page.

The script runs `window.fbAsyncInit` from a `window.setTimeout(..., 0)`, causing your code to be run after the Facebook script has been completely loaded and initialized.